# Typecast string to component name (class name) in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to convert this string "BoxOneComponent" to BoxOneComponent (class name). How to typecast in angular 2? Is there something like .toString() to typecast to class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is create an object like this

```
let classes = {
    BoxOneComponent: BoxOneComponent
};
```

And call it like this

```
let myVar = new this.classes[this.myString]();
```